# Update UI after callback within AsyncTask doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have callbacks within an AsyncTask doInBackground. I would like to update the UI after the callbacks are completed. My problem is that I can't return inside my callback response, so I'm not sure how to do this. Basically, I would like to return myString from my callback response to onPostExecute.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

    MyAsyncTask() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

            Util.syncMessages(token, new Util.OnSyncMessages() {
                @Override
                public void onSyncMessages(boolean success, String myString) {
                    if (success) {
                        return myString; // can't return here
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String returnString) {
        super.onPostExecute(returnString);
        // would like to update UI with myString here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems hard to return the value in inner class,hope this helps:

```
 private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Void> {

    MyAsyncTask() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Object... params) {

            Util.syncMessages(token, new Util.OnSyncMessages() {
                @Override
                public void onSyncMessages(boolean success, String myString) {
                    if (success) {
                        //return myString; // can't return here
                        publishProgress(myString);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

     @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        String str = values[0];
        //do something with str in main Thread.

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

1- `onPostExecute` is a method that you should `override` not create.

2- Change the extends class to this `AsyncTask<Param, Progress, Result>` see the example below

```
//AsyncTask<Param, Progress, Result>
private class PotatoAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {

    private static String passedString;

    PotatoAsyncTask() {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // In the UI thread
        // before calling doInBackground()
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // In another thread than the UI thread
        // do what you want here
        Util.syncMessages(token, new Util.OnSyncMessages() {
            @Override
            public void onSyncMessages(boolean success, String myString) {
                if (success) {
                    passedString = myString;
                    return; // this is not the return of doInBackground
                }
            }
        });

        return returnString;// return what you want in here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String returnString) {
        super.onPostExecute(returnString);
        // In UI thread
        // after doInBackground is completely done
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(String returnString) {
        super.onCancelled(returnString);
        // in case the doInBackground was cancelled at one point but there is still a result
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I need to know how to handle the callback functions inside doInBackground. For example, in the example I posted, Util.syncMessages returns "String error" (among other things) and I want to know to return that to onPostExecute... (I am not able to put "return" inside my callback)

Comment: @Primico ... just so I can clarify this. you give this AsyncTask an object and you want a String back, Right?

Comment: @Primico ... so you want to exit the `doInBackground` when you get that error ?

Comment: set a global field inside of the class ... if it complain then make it static ... the important thing is to keep it inside of `PotatoAsyncTask`

Comment: I edited my post again to make it even more clear. I thought about creating a variable and setting the value when I get the callback response, but by the time the value is set, onPostExecute is already executed.

Comment: @Primico     Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138169/discussion-between-mohammedalsafwan-and-primico).